# Cannot find Kotlin typealias in multi-module Android project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, maven-3

I'm working on a multi-module project and the project is no longer compiling.  The setup is that some modules are in another git repo (repo "A") and publish the modules' AAR outputs to maven.  Then the other git repo (repo "B") pulls in those AARs via maven.

It worked yesterday before I started moving over more modules from one repo to another (it's a multi phase effort).  It's currently failing because one module in repo "A" creates a Kotlin `typealias` and another module in repo "B" tries to use that `typealias`.  Now, it cannot find the `typealias` in repo "B"'s module.

I have looked in the resulting AAR and see the `typealias` defined where I expect.

Does a Kotlin `typealias` need some kind of special setup to be used from an AAR?

Comment: Does B depend on A? And is it properly linked?

Comment: Yes.  And the build.gradle file for the module definitely includes it correctly.  I know the AAR has the typealias and I know repo "B" is pulling the maven dependency correctly (I can see in the gradle output that it's getting the right maven snapshot version).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did you guys have found the answer? adding the accepted solution did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following to your module's build.gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).